# How to use "Message" class in Android?

Tags: android

I just wanted to ask about the Firebase Documentation about "sending messages to multiple devices". 
Link to the page: [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/send-multiple?authuser=0)

Ive copied this code into my project:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3mgg.png)

But, when pasted, the .builder() is not accepted.

Does anyone know, how to solve this ? Thanks.

Code:

```
Message message = Message
            .builder() //this is not accepted.
            .setNotification(new Notification(
                    "$GOOG up 1.43% on the day",
                    "$GOOG gained 11.80 points to close at 835.67, up 1.43% on the day."))
            .setCondition(condition)
            .build();
```

Comment: Have you set up the firebase correctly? Have you tested with topics? Does it work with them?

Comment: are you importing the right Message class?

Comment: @Aman I have installed the dependency Implementation 11.8.0 of FCM. I have successfully sent a notification with the notification composer.

Comment: @Quinn there are 3 Message classes, nur non of them is working.  Maybe my dependency is outdated? When i use the newest dependency, i get an error.

Comment: Okay. What error are you getting when you use the newest dependency?

Comment: Please add the logcat errors you are seeing when you run this code

Comment: @Aman now i updated the firebase Core dependency to 16.0.7 and now, i am not getting an error anymore. But still, the .builder() will not be accepted.

Comment: @JoelB What do you mean by not accepted? Is there any error you are getting?

Comment: @Aman the .builder() part is in red color, so it does not exist for using

Comment: @JoelB did you check the imports? Are you importing the correct Message class?Apologies for late reply.